# nextjs Error: Requested and resolved page mismatch

Tags: next.js

Im getting the error in my nextjs app when running a build `Error: Requested and resolved page mismatch: //beard-oil-50ml-patchouli-lime-and-cedarwood /beard-oil-50ml-patchouli-lime-and-cedarwood`

How can I resolve this?

[slug][catSlug].js

```
import React from 'react'
import head from 'next/head'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import Options from '../../components/Product/Options'
import { request, gql } from 'graphql-request'
import media from '../../components/atoms/Media'
import Price from '../../components/atoms/Price'
import ScrollToTop from '../../components/atoms/ScrollToTop'
import * as palette from '../../components/atoms/Variables'
import Images from '../../components/Product/Images'
import AddToCart from '../../components/atoms/AddToCart'


export async function getStaticProps({ params }) {
}
export async function getStaticPaths() {
```

}

```
const Product = ({ product=[], options=[], parent=[] }) => {
  // const parentCat = product.parent && options.filter(products => products.slug === product.parent)[0].slug
  // const newPrice = (parent && !price) ? products.filter(products => products.slug === product.parent).map(product => product.price && product.price).toString() : price
  const newPrice = (parent && parent.price && !product.price) ? parent.price : product.price
  const material = parent && parent.material ? parent.material : product.material
  const ingredients = parent && parent.ingredients ? parent.ingredients : product.ingredients

  const moreInfo = (
    <>
      {product.features && <SubLabel>Features</SubLabel>}
      {product.features && <SubText>{product.features}</SubText>}
      {product.quantity && <SubLabel>Quantity</SubLabel>}
      {product.quantity && <SubText>{product.quantity}</SubText>}
      {product.material && <SubLabel>Material</SubLabel>}
      {product.material && <SubText>{product.material}</SubText>}
      {product.ingredients && <SubLabel>Ingredients</SubLabel>}
      {product.ingredients && <SubText>{product.ingredients}</SubText>}    
      {product.burnTime && <SubLabel>Burn Time</SubLabel>}
      {product.burnTime && <SubText>{product.burnTime.includes('m') ? `approx. ${product.burnTime.replace('m', ' minutes')}` : `${product.burnTime}`}</SubText>}
      {product.weight && <SubLabel>Weight</SubLabel>}
      {product.weight && <SubText>{product.weight.includes('g') ? `${product.weight}` : `${product.weight}kg`}</SubText>}
      {(product.height || product.width || product.depth || product.strap || product.length || product.diameter) && <SubLabel>Dimensions</SubLabel>}
      {(product.height || product.width || product.depth || product.strap || product.length || product.diameter) && 
      <SubText>
        {product.height && <DimensionsText><DimensionsLabel>Height:</DimensionsLabel> {product.height}cm</DimensionsText>}
        {product.width && <DimensionsText><DimensionsLabel>Width:</DimensionsLabel> {product.width}cm</DimensionsText>}
        {product.depth && <DimensionsText><DimensionsLabel>Depth:</DimensionsLabel> {product.depth}cm</DimensionsText>}
        {product.strap && <DimensionsText><DimensionsLabel>Strap:</DimensionsLabel> {product.strap}cm</DimensionsText>}
        {product.length && <DimensionsText><DimensionsLabel>Length:</DimensionsLabel> {product.length.includes('m') ? `${product.length}` : `${product.length}cm`}</DimensionsText>}
        {product.diameter && <DimensionsText><DimensionsLabel>Diameter:</DimensionsLabel> {product.diameter}cm</DimensionsText>}
      </SubText>}
      {product.uses && <SubLabel>Uses</SubLabel>}
      <SubText>{product.uses}</SubText>
      {product.directions && <SubLabel>Directions</SubLabel>}
      {product.directions}
      {product.caution && <SubLabel>Caution</SubLabel>}
      {product.caution}
      {product.parentCaution && <SubLabel>Caution</SubLabel>}
      {product.parentCaution}
      {product.size && <SubLabel>Size</SubLabel>}
      {product.size}
    </>
  )
  const router = useRouter()
  const { catSlug } = router.query
  return(
    <>
    <ScrollToTop />
    <Grid>
      <Half>
        <div></div>
        {/* <Images key="1" images={product.images} img={product.img} thumb={product.thumb} alt={product.name} /> */}
      
      </Half> 
      <Half>
         <InfoWrap>
          <Title>{product.name}</Title>
          <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: parent && parent.overview }} />
          {/* <Description dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: desc && desc.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")}} 
          /> */}
      <OptionsWrap>
        {options.length > 1 && options.map(option => 
          <Options key={option.slug} {...option} newPrice={newPrice} />  
        )}
        </OptionsWrap>
        <ButtonWrap>
            <AddToCartWrap>
              <PriceWrap>
                <Price
                  oldPrice={product.oldPrice} 
                  price={newPrice}
                />
              </PriceWrap>
            {(product.stock === 'no' || newPrice === null || newPrice === '')
            ? <Stock>Not in stock</Stock> :
                <AddToCart
                  className="snipcart-add-item"
                  dataItemId={product.id}
                  dataItemName={product.name}
                  dataItemPrice={newPrice}
                  dataItemImage={`https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/${product.img}`}
                  dataItemUrl={`/${catSlug}/${product.slug}`}
                  data-item-has-taxes-included="true"
                  >Add To Cart
                </AddToCart>
              }
            </AddToCartWrap>
          </ButtonWrap>
          <ShowDesktop>
          {moreInfo}
          </ShowDesktop>
        </InfoWrap>
        <ShowMobile>
          {moreInfo}
        </ShowMobile>
      </Half>
    </Grid>
     
    
    </>
  )
}

export default Product
```